# Java - newline option is not working as expected When running program on Linux

Tags: java, newline, bufferedwriter

I have an application where I want to write a string to the file as newline at EOF.

My program executes on Linux OS and the file that I want to to write resides in a windows shared folder.

Problem: I am able to add string to the file as a newline, when I run the program on windows OS using eclipse.
But when deploy and run the app on Linux box, string gets added to the file but not as a newline.

Eg: 
Let’s say if I want to add a new string as ‘test user’ to the file, this is how it adds.

```
Hr usr 
Hi usr
Jk  usrtest user
```

I want it to be like

```
Hr usr
Hi usr
Jk usrt
test user

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileUrl, true)); 
bw.newLine();
//didn’t write newline when I deployed it to Linux box
bw.write();
//OR
bw.append(System.lineSeperator() + “mystring”);
//didn’t write newline when I deployed it to Linux box
//OR
bw.append(“\r\n” + “mystring”);
//didn’t write newline when I deployed it to Linux box
```

I am pretty sure code wise nothing is wrong, somewhere UNIX or Windows getting confused with the newline separation.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeevan.

Comment: In Windows, newline is `\r\n`, and on Unix it's just `\n`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp : wanted to right the same comment as well (+1). Known and classic issue when working cross windows/linux.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You're correct of course, but many native windows apps now also respect just `\n` as a line break. Notepad is now the only popular one I'm aware of that doesn't...

Comment: As a side note - please consider upvoting my answer, or selecting it as the question's answer, if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case "\r\n" is working, I had a deployment issue, so it did not update the class in web logic sever while trying "\r\n".

Thanks for your interest in my post.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is found here :

```
bw.append(“\r\n” + “mystring”);
```

As mentioned by [Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp), breakline behaves differently on Linux.
For your Linux deployment you should use "\n" instead of "\r\n".

A classic solution to this problem is creating a Utility class/method which checks which OS the JVM is running on, then returning a value based on the OS type (a Map of such values would work nicely, IMHO).

Comment: Yes! you both are right, but I access the file on a windows machine using NotePad.

Comment: @jeevan : Be careful with manipulating a file in windows which should later be handled under Linux. I had issues with editing a script file in windows, which then had all of its breaklines replaced with the windows style breaklines. This caused the script to become un-operational on linux......
As a side note - please consider upvoting this answer, or selecting it as the question's answer, if you found it helpful.

Comment: It doesn't let me up vote, because of my reputation level.!

Answer (score 1):

Other than `\n` as mentioned in other comments, you can try `String.format("%n")` for new line.

Or even you can use `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Comment: You can do [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) since Java 7. It's shorter and there are no ugly string literals.

Comment: @Michael, OP is already using the same. I was just providing the alternatives for which he may be comfortable with.